# How to filter an array of objects in Kendo Grid (AngularJs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Document object like this:

```
{"id": 1, "annotation": "some text", "signers": [{ "id": 32, "name": "Bob", "address": {"country": "USA"}}, 
{ "id": 44, "name": "Bill", "address": {"country": "Canada"}}]}
```

Documents are displayed in a Kendo grid, and one of the columns is for signers. How is it possible to filter signers by name (and also by country, but that is less relevant)? How to filter an array of objects?

I've been trying to figure out how to write a custom `filter` function and do all the filtering on client side, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Set` of the names or countries to search for and call `Set#has` in the callback for `Array#filter`.

```js
let doc = {"id": 1, "annotation": "some text", "signers": [{ "id": 32, "name": "Bob", "address": {"country": "USA"}}, 
{ "id": 44, "name": "Bill", "address": {"country": "Canada"}}]};
const names = new Set(["Bob", "Joe"]);
doc.signers = doc.signers.filter(({name})=>names.has(name));
console.log(doc);
```